# Model imported from ZBrush into 3DS Max looks very distorted but only when rendered

Tags: import, max, distortion, 3ds

I imported a very low poly object into ZBrush, sculpted it, then ZRemeshered and projected the details onto a lower poly object to make the normal map. After that, I exported the lower poly .obj into 3DS Max, where it looked perfect in the viewport but completely distorted when rendered. It doesn't have any materials or anything, this is just the model itself. Screenshots:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qiswlfwlkf6f7hj/normal.png?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/cba1schavgl5mm8/distortion.png?dl=0

Thanks a lot!

Comment: try to save as 3ds file...

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In the end I don't know what I did but it started working normally